# $ R(t) = R_0 - \int_0^t v(T) dT , v(t) = \tanh(\int_0^t \frac{C dT}{R^2(T)})$ ??

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, closed-form, inverse-function

Let $R_0,C$ be positive real constants and consider the following differential equation :

$$ R(t) = R_0 - \int_0^t v(T) dT $$
$$ v(t) = \tanh(\int_0^t \frac{C dT}{R^2(T)})$$

How to solve this ?
How to simplify it or change it in a simpler differential equation ?
How to solve it numerically ?

I considered the special functions  :

$$ \frac{d B(x)}{d x} = - \tanh(\frac{C}{B(x)^2}) $$
$$  \frac{d C(x)}{d x} = - \frac{1}{\tanh(\frac{C}{x^2})} $$

( constants of integration may be picked as desired )

As possible helping functions but not sure if they are related.

The functional inverses of $R(t),v(t)$ are also of interest to me.

In particular how do we find $y$ such that

$$ R(y) = 0 $$

??

I assume iterative methods exists ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you presented are integral equations. You can transform them into differential equations,
\begin{align}
R'(t)&= -v(t),& R(0)&=R_0,\\
v'(t)&=(1-v(t)^2)\frac{C}{R(t)^2},&v(0)&=0.
\end{align}
This now can be solved numerically like any other first order system. One has to observe for the singularity at $R(t)=0$.

Comment: How did you find the $(1 - v(t)^2) $ part in the second equation ?
I know the derivative of $tanh(x) $is $1 - tanh^2(x)$. Not sure how that reduces to a function of $v(t)$. ( the $C/R(t)^2$ part comes from the chain rule i understand ).
Also im not familiar with numerical methods , im new to differential equations sorry

Comment: Yes, that is the chain rule, $v(t)=\tanh(u(t))\implies $v'(t)=(1-\tanh^2(u(t)))u'(t)=(1-v(t)^2))u'(t)$. // For the numerics, one usually starts with the Euler method for a scalar equation, then for some system for the concept of a solver. Then the same for one of the RK2 methods as the most simple higher order method. Then to see how much order matters, use the "classical" RK4 method. After that use libraries of ODE solvers.

Comment: oh I see. Thank u.